# Зависимость быстродействия кода от используемых средств Python

Tags: python, производительность

Ясно, что быстродействие зависит от правильно выбранного алгоритма.
Но также очевидно, что быстродействие должно зависеть и от выбранных средств языка (что в случае интерпретируемого Python приобретает особую важность), а неудачный выбор снизит его даже при правильно выбранном алгоритме.

**Вопрос: есть ли способ (кроме имитации) для определения того, какие средства Python быстрее, а какие медленнее?** Например, какие библиотеки написаны на С ("быстрые"), а какие - на Python ("не-такие-быстрые")? Или (условно) одинаковая ли скорость поиска или сортировки в разных типах? И т.д.

Это могут быть как какие-то встроенные средства, так и одна чудо-страница в документации.

*Цель: практическая - писать быстро работающие программы. Теоретические сравнения экзотических комбинаций не прошу.*

Comment: Хороший вопрос ;-)

Comment: @Namerek, так он и возник после вторых суток обдумывания вашего комментария мне "Большие списки таскать то еще удовольствие". Ясно, что в том случае больше речь всё же шла про алгоритм, но понимание вопроса скорости обработки повлияло бы и на исходную идею входной последовательности (я продолжаю анализировать ту задачу и ваши варианты решения).

Comment: Эээ, ну известно, что для больших числовых массивов обычно лучше использовать `Numpy`, он написан на `C++` и оптимизирован для работы с такими данными. Так то вообще большинство библиотек для питона пишется на `C++` либо современной версии `Fortran` и затачивается под максимальное быстродействие. А вот встроенные типы питона сделаны максимально гибкими и поэтому они обычно довольно медленные в сравнении со специальными библиотеками.

Comment: @CrazyElf да (`Numpy` ещё и GIL отключает даже), но есть ли все подобные знания в каком-то упорядоченном виде или в каком-то tool? А то даже в учебниках авторы вдруг мимоходом пишут: "Кстати, вот это - быстро".

Comment: @Сергей Чтобы прям в одном месте - кажется, нет. Я вообще хотел как-то написать такой `FAQ` именно по способам ускорения работы кода в питоне, но так что-то и не собрался. Способы сильно разные и чтобы прям в одном месте всё было собрано я вроде бы не встречал.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ясно, спасибо. Может, тогда я однажды (в не очень далёком будущем) и напишу, если реально сподоблюсь программистом снова стать:-) и упорядочу эти знания в процессе обретения. Хотя, конечно, уже написанные кем-то умным были бы лучше.

Comment: Кстати, не всегда скорость - это главное. Случаи разные бывают. Бывает, что нужно экономить не время, а место. А бывает, что в них не упирается ничего, а главное - это понятность кода.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, это абсолютно верно и понятно (я достаточно писал на ассемблере в прошлом). Но данный вопрос именно про скорость. И не зря на собеседованиях алгоритмическая секция важной считается.

Comment: Начать стоит с https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно изучу внимательно.

Comment: @Namerek хороший вопрос, но что-то вы бережете свои оценки :(

Comment: @Dmitry, Сергей понял о чем я, просто в одной из наших с ним дискуссий относительно бинарного поиска, он утверждал что нет никакой разницы по быстродействию, между вариантом со сравнением и вариантом с использованием списков. Я ему набросал варианты где разница по быстродействию растет в геометрической прогрессии относительно количества итераций. По факту мое сообщение - своего рода подколка)

Comment: @Namerek, для точности: я не утверждал там ничего, я задал там вопрос. "Но как-то надо же задать диапазон? Не все ли равно, списки, строки?", и после ответа на него вежливо и кротко ответил: "Ясно, спасибо". Для моего текущего уровня знания языка будет несколько нелепо спорить по серьёзным вопросам с людьми, которые явно его глубже знают. Но да, вопрос тут я задал после этого + курс по алгоримам сейчас прохожу, после которого вернусь к тому примеру.

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо. Как понимаю, +1 от вас получил:-). На самом деле я действительно слегка удивлён, что мои вопросы обычно не плюсуются, хотя я их стараюсь задавать после детальной проверки и на интересные, как мне кажется темы. Но, вероятно, интересны они только мне. Что хорошо, ответы я получил на 100% моих вопросов, это важнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суммирую в ответе основное, что мне посоветовали в комментариях к вопросу:

1. "для больших числовых массивов обычно лучше использовать Numpy, он написан на C++ и оптимизирован для работы с такими данными. Так то вообще большинство библиотек для питона пишется на C++ либо современной версии Fortran и затачивается под максимальное быстродействие. А вот встроенные типы питона сделаны максимально гибкими и поэтому они обычно довольно медленные в сравнении со специальными библиотеками."
2. Начать стоит с [PythonSpeed PerformanceTips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)